# Is it legal to buy a veterinary drug from a Canadian online store from the U.S.?

Tags: united-states

I have a prescription from my veterinary for a chronic condition that my pet has. However, the FDA approved medication is astronomically more expensive in the US than it is in Canada. Is it legal for me to personally purchase and import my pet’s medicine from an online Canadian e-store?

The laws on this seem extremely unclear. I’ve read about Trump and Biden both being involved in allowing personal medical imports from Canada, while some sources say it is still totally illegal, and some sources say it is technically illegal but openly not enforced whatsoever. Just how legal is this? I live in New York.

Comment: "Is it legal for me to personally purchase and import my pet’s medicine from an online Canadian e-store?" That is ambiguous. Are you intending to order it online or travel to canada, buy it there and import it personally? That could make a big difference, as taking personal medications with you over the border is typically legal, while having it sent by mail may not be.